# Zero-based month on Django Template Tag

Tags: python, django

I was using the now template tag on django and realized it doesn't have a way to format month as zero-based. Cause javascript has it's month zero-based that can be handy.

The way I figured to quick-fix this was `{% now 'd, m-1, Y' %}`. Although it solves the problem, I'm not fully satisfied.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Or just writing a template tag?

Answer (score 0):

The `{% now %}` template tag accepts the same formatting string as the `date` template filter.

"m" is a zero-based numeric month. So you would do:

```
{% now "d, m, Y" %}
```

Which outputs:

```
28, 03, 2014
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#date for more information on formatting dates and times.

Months in Python are 1-based:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> d = date.today()
>>> d.month
3
```

Comment: which is march, the same month we're in. Right?

Comment: That's not zero-based, then.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's not a zero based month... the output is "03". I guess I don't understand what you're needing to do.

Comment: I meant zero-based because it should start at 0. Like python, c, etc is zero-based when it comes to iterable data structures. That said, january would be the 0 month just like javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding what you're needing to do. Months in Python are 1-based. I've updated my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: I want it zero-based. That way, we being on march it should show 2, instead of 3. That being said january would be 0. That might be handful since javascript month representation begins at 0. And since we render templates which contain javascript, so...

Comment: In that case, you're probably better off not using the built-in template tags and just formatting the custom date representation in your model or in a custom template tag.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Haha. It certainly seems that way sometimes, doesn't it.

Comment: I just balanced it before the people that don't read answers but still downvote because it's already downvoted comes in. And because it's a helpful answer indeed

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue... here's how I do it with a simple custom filter:

```
@register.filter(name='dateWithZeroBasedMonth')
def dateWithZeroBasedMonth(value):
    if value is None:
        value = date.today()
    year = value.year
    month = value.month
    day = value.day
    return str(year) + "," + str(month-1) + "," + str(day)
```

Not elegant, but it works for me and returns a simple date in a format that is accepted by Javascript's Date() function.